# Should you return a passed parameter just to signal mutability in Java

Tags: java

I am sure this is more of a subjective question however I am curious people's oppinions...

Today at work I saw the following method....

```
public T execute(T dto){...return dto;}
```

This seemed redundant to me, in my mind this was better....

```
public void execute(T dto)
```

For now in this method lets say the following is called....

```
dto.setProperty(something);
```

But a colleague (and a few StackOverflow posts) suggest this is bad because it doesn't suggest that the method may be altering the T object. However this should be reflected on the object in the stack so why do I need a return.

Is this a valid reason, to me it seems to me this has to cause increases in overhead (although in all fairness we are using Java here)

Any insight as to which is better?

Comment: These 2 method signatures are not comparable, one has a return type and the other doesn't. Without knowing what execute is supposed to do it is very hard to say which is best.

Comment: I don't see how `public T execute(T dto)` suggests that it *does* change `dto`. This seems pulled out of thin air to me.

Comment: @TheCat From what I understand of the question, what the method does is irrelevant. It might be altering `dto`, and returning `T` is somehow supposed to clarify that. I guess if you make a copy of `dto`, then change and return that, it'd make a bit of sense, but there's really no reason I can't have a method `String execute(String dto)` which returns a String related to `dto` in some way but *doesn't* change it (immutable).

Comment: @Jackie Does the `execute` method actually change the `dto` instance provided and then returning `dto` (not a copy)? If so I'd say that's a more misleading design as it gives the impression that when passing in `dto`, that instance won't be changed and that to get the modified version you have to store the result - much like many of the `String` methods, such as `replaceFirst`/`replaceAll`.

Comment: Trying to clarify, wow that was quick... yes it does but the original object still has the stack entry for the object on the heap right? So why would I need to return?

Comment: The problem is the method name `execute`, cannot be generilized regarding that matter. If a method mutates the state of the parameter, it should be reflected by it's name. Then if the parameter is immutable it should have the return type, otherwise void. Then it will be easy to figure whether it mutates the state of the passed in instance or creates a new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on what `T` is, whether T is immutable, and what `execute` does.  This question couldn't really be more generic and specifics matter.

```
void addPerson(Club clubFullOfPeople, Person person);

T clone(T t);
```

would both be valid and strike me as good design.

To answer your exact question - should you return to signal mutability?  That absolutely strikes me as something that would signal IM-mutability if anything so, no, absolutely not, but you need clearer variable names, documentation etc. to communicate this.

Comment: `that would signal IM-mutability` +1 on that. In functional languages like ocaml where you can have functions with side effects the return type of these functions are usually the unit type (a singleton value with no interesting properties so you could say it doesn't return anything (interesting). It is somewhat like void, except it *has* a value). Point is, returning void in java would be analogous.

Comment: "That absolutely strikes me as something that would signal IM-mutability" Right if it returned the object it would signal immutability right? so since it is a mutable object it should not be returned is that what you are saying?

Comment: A mutable object should not be returned after mutating it, that just leads to two references to the same object in the same line of code probably by different names, which is nothing but confusion.

Comment: great that is exactly the overhead I was getting at, I was just bad at explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an *unreasonable* style, it's simply a decision that should be made (project by project) - go with the style used in the working environment.  Next project/job may choose differently.

Answer (score 0):

Neither style implies that the DTO can or cannot be altered.  In fact, if anything, the first form would rather suggested that the parameterized DTO is *not* being altered, but if there are changes that are being made, they will be made in the returned object.

Advantages of returning the DTO:

1. Calls can be chained (this may be good or bad depending on the coding style and the use of the actual methods/objects).  For example jQuery is built such that just about every call can be chained.
2. You can return a null value or some other object/form of the DTO to signify a failure of some sorts

In your "preferred" notation, the only way you can signify a failure is via Runtime Exceptions.  Without know what the `execute` method is supposed to accomplish, this may be okay, or may indicate a larger problem in that Exceptions are being used to handle flow control (a bad thing).

Net result?  I don't think there is a "better" solution - just something that matches more what you are currently doing in your existing codebase.